# Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace | Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am getting consistent problem in using Eclipse Marketplace. I am using Eclipse Neon. I am using broadband internet connection and my network configuration for Eclipse is native.

The error is:

> Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
>     Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed
>
> This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
>       Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
>     Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
>   Connection failed
>
> This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
>   Address family not supported by protocol family: connect

Screenshot of error:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Solved it. Follow following steps:-

1. Open command prompt.
2. Right click on top left of command prompt, select properties, and enable quick edit mode.
3. Type following line on cmd:-  setx `_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, 
       Hit enter.
4. cmd will prompt:- SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it's just proxy information:

Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections

- Active Provider: Manual
- HTTP  : with proxy value
- HTTPS : with proxy value
- SOCKS : without proxy value

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Windows->Preferences->General->Network Connections->Set Active Provider to Manual->Schema  to HTTPS,HTTP,SOCKS->Click OK->Restart Eclipse