# Eclipse (Mars) Modeling Tools - cannot open "Marketplace" or "Installation Details"

Tags: eclipse, java-7

I'm having an issue regarding Eclipse Modeling Tools in Mars release
(I'm working with some legacy tools that have already proven to have issues with later eclipse editions, so using the latest version is not an easy option)

I can neither open the Marketplace, nor can I open the Installation Details (Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details).

This is obviously inconvenient when trying to install software the recommended way (or - at all) and checking for already installed software.

An often cited fix is to try other network settings (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections), but that didn't help.

Neither did i manage to fix it by installing the marketplace client through "Help -> Install new Software" or manually downloading it.

Thanks in advance for any Help!

---

Further Details:

This is the Error log when trying to open the Marketplace

```
Message:
Unhandled event loop exception

Exception Stack Trace:
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1994)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14720)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplacePage.createTab(MarketplacePage.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplacePage.createCatalogTab(MarketplacePage.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplacePage.createControl(MarketplacePage.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 38 more

Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
```

And this the log when I try to open Installation Details

```
Message:
Unhandled event loop exception

ExceptionStackTrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1994)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14720)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.InstallationDialog.createFolderItems(InstallationDialog.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.InstallationDialog.createDialogArea(InstallationDialog.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.InstallationDialog.createContents(InstallationDialog.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog$1.run(AboutDialog.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog.buttonPressed(AboutDialog.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.AboutHandler.execute(AboutHandler.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
```

adding "-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to the eclipse.ini (as suggested here: [IPv4Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720780/cannot-open-eclipse-marketplace-cannot-install-remote-marketplace-locations-can) and here [IPv4Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839879/cannot-open-eclipse-marketplace-cannot-install-remote-marketplace-locations-c)) didn't change anything either.

my eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vm
/home/gilbert/Development Software/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin
#/home/gilbert/Development Software/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-vmargs
#-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

after trying to add "marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api*" to the Proxy Bypass setting (as suggested here: [ProxyBypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179874/eclipse-error-when-trying-to-open-eclipse-marketplace-cannot-open-eclipse-marke)),
this is the error i get when trying to open the marketplace:

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
marketplace.eclipse.org
Cannot resolve host

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
marketplace.eclipse.org
```

and the error-log when trying to see the Installation Details appears to be the same as before.

My OS is Linux Mint 19.1

---

What i actually want to do is to use [ATL reactive](https://github.com/atlanmod/org.eclipse.atl.reactive) to convert a [Palladio](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/palladio-40-eclipse-mars) component model into a UML model an Java Code.

I am using Eclipse Mars because Eclipse 2019-03 had even more issues and Eclipse Mars was the latest Edition at the time of ATL reactives last update, and java 7 because Eclipse Mars refused to launch using any other Version. (as you see in my eclipse.ini,

Also, "The import org.antlr cannot be resolved", and I can't seem to find any other way to install it than the Marketplace, and I'd like to check if it isn't already preinstalled in Eclipse Mars Modeling Tools and if so, in which version, which i cannot check because of the "Installation Details" issue.

Comment: The NPE in TabFolder.gtk_switch_page might be [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486069) which is marked as fixed on Eclipse 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the Eclipse Forum suggsted that this could be caused by my OS being too new.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1807853/#msg_1807853

So I fixed it by installing a dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04.